# Update image from directory of images in C# via await and async

Tags: c#, async-await

I am trying to build a simple page with just an image on it which gets pulled randomly from a directory which users will drop images into. Here is what I have so far, and it works, just now I need to add the async piece so the page doesn't refresh each time a new image loads via the timer.

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;

namespace WindSlider
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public static int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\path\SliderImages", "*.jpg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length; // count images in directory
        public static Random rnd = new Random(); //randomize image
        int imageNumber = rnd.Next(1, fCount); // creates a number between 1 and # of images in directory

        private void loadNextImage()
        {
          imgPicture.ImageUrl = string.Format(@"SliderImages\Wind{0}.jpg", imageNumber);
        }

        public void tmrNextImage_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          loadNextImage();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is where I think I need to start heading, am I on the right path?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(GetImagesAsync));
    }

private async Task GetImagesAsync()
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        image = Image.FromStream(
        new MemoryStream(await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(string.Format(@"C:\Users\path\SliderImages\Wind{0}.jpg", imageNumber))));

    }
```

I'm just hung up on the order of operations here and which is the best way to approach this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to use images from the local disk or from the web? When does the page refresh? The loading of an Image has nothing to do with the page in your case. Do you have a WPF or a Windows Store App?

Comment: Local network disk. The page will refresh currently via the Timer(tmrNextImage_Tick) control every 30seconds. I would like it to refresh every 30 seconds without the entire page reloading as it currently does. WPF, its JUST a simple one page app with JUST an image on it - this will ultimately be a portion of a dashboard I am building.

Comment: The page does not reload if you change the `Source` of an `Image` control. But I do not know which kind of control do you use. The `Image` Control have no `ImageUrl` property.
I am also not know how large your Images are, but usually it is not neccessary to load them async.

Comment: I just dropped an Image control on the Default.aspx page, with the id of "imgPicture". As I said it works, but currently the page reloads everytime the loadNextImage() is called it seems. 

The images are all under 100k each. I think I'm close but I seem to have some conflict with the .FromStream if I reference it to the imgPicture.

Comment: Sorry, I have not thought about ASP.NET, only to client-only Solutions...
Every time if a server script is called, the page will reload unless you use a client script (JavaScript) to load the next Image. I will try to write a correct answer for you

Answer (score 0):

My Solution has two parts, but without async/await on server side. The first part is a generic handler *GetImage.ashx*:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    int id;
    if (int.TryParse(context.Request.QueryString["id"], out id))
    {
        Image img = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\path\SliderImages\Wind"+id+".jpg");
        //Load Image id from the folder with

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            ms.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
        }
    }
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
}
```

In the aspx file is a JavaScript the loads random Images every 30s:

```
<img id="myImage" />

<script>
    function loadNextRandomImage() {
        var rndNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        document.getElementById("myImage").setAttribute("src", "GetImage.ashx?id=" + rndNumber);

        //call it once again in 30s
        setTimeout(loadNextRandomImage, 30000);
    }
    loadNextRandomImage();
</script>
```

I hope it help you.